# how to allocate space to a text as much as it needs and then the rest to the right side textInput

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a `Text` component and a `TextInput` on a row beside each other, I what the `Text` to get space as much as it needs then leave the rest of the width of the device for the `TextInput`. How can I do that with `flexbox`? or any other tools? does `Dimensions` give me the length of a `Text` so that i can use it to allocate that to the text?

Comment: the problem is that when someone doesn't know how to do something, expecting that person to provide code is funny as if I know how to do I could code it !!! before giving a -1 as soon as you see a question without code in it, it's better to give some hints to the person!!

Comment: If you knew the width of the text, you could use the ` calc` method in css. Considering you do not know the width of the text. You're going to need to use javascript to get the total width of the container, and then width of the text element. You can then set the width of the input to totalWidth - texWidth.

Comment: @KyleRichardson thanks indeed for your help, could you add some more explanation with code and post it as the answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the gist of what is going on from the snippet below. Adapt this to your needs.

```js
var containerWidth = document.getElementById("container").offsetWidth;
var labelWidth = document.getElementById("label").offsetWidth;
var inputWidth = containerWidth - labelWidth - 1 + "px"
document.getElementById("input").setAttribute( "style", `width: ${inputWidth}` );
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
}
#label {
  float: left;
}
#container, #input, #label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <label for="input" id="label">Label</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
</div>
```